# Diophantine method

Tags: diophantine-equations, math-history

I am having a problem in understanding the following problem:

Find $\sqrt{15}$ using Diophantine method.

I am aware of what Diophantine equations are, but totally stuck when asked to find $\sqrt{15}$, with $3$ decimal places.

What does it mean?

Comment: Never heard that phrase before, in this context.  The usual thing would be the standard Babylonian method:   get $\sqrt N$ by guessing $x_0$ and then letting $x_1=\frac 12\times \left( x_0+\frac N{x_0}\right)$ and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Pell equation method ends up with this: given a pair of (non-negative) integers $x,y$ that satisfy $x^2 - 15 y^2 = 1,$ 
we get as many solutions as might be needed by applying
$$ (x,y)  \mapsto (4x+15y, x+4y). $$
The ratios get closer and closer to $\sqrt{15}$ since
$$ \left( \frac{x}{y} \right)^2 - 15 = \frac{1}{y^2}    $$
$$ \left( \frac{x}{y}  - \sqrt{15} \right) \left( \frac{x}{y}  + \sqrt{15} \right)  = \frac{1}{y^2}    $$
$$ \left( \frac{x}{y}  - \sqrt{15} \right)   = \frac{1}{y^2  \left( \frac{x}{y}  + \sqrt{15} \right)}    $$
So the error is $ \frac{1}{y^2  \left( \frac{x}{y}  + \sqrt{15} \right)}, $ very close to $\frac{1}{ 2 \sqrt{15}y^2   }$ and less than $\frac{1}{7 y^2}$
We get
$$  (4,1) , 4.0 $$
$$  (31, 8) , 3.875 $$
$$     (244,63), \; 3.87301 $$
$$ (1921,496) , \; 3.87298    $$
$$ (15124,3905), \; 3.872983355  $$
$$ (119071, 30744), \; 3.872983346 $$

If we switch to a negative target, the ratios are slightly smaller than $\sqrt{15}.$ Using $-6,$ the errors come out $ \frac{-6}{y^2  \left( \frac{x}{y}  + \sqrt{15} \right)}, $ very close to $\frac{-6}{ 2 \sqrt{15}y^2   }$ and less than $\frac{6}{7 y^2}$ in absolute value...
$$  (3,1) , 3.0 $$
$$  (27, 7) , 3.857 $$
$$     (213,55), \; 3.8727 $$
$$ (1677,433) , \; 3.872979    $$
$$ (13203,3409), \; 3.872983  $$
$$ ( 103947 , 26839 ), \; 3.872983345 $$

Comment: woah, thank you for your generous clarification. Greatly appreciated! :)